# C++ Novice regarding Vectors and for/while loops

Tags: c++, loops, vector, for-loop, while-loop

I’m trying to make something that will take lines of input from the user, separate them into strings in a vector, then print them one at a time (8 per line).
so far this is what I’ve got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<string> svec1;
    string temp;
    while(getline(cin, temp)) //stores lines of text in temp
    {
        if(temp.empty()) //checks if temp is empty, exits loop if so.
            break;
        stringstream ss(temp);
        string word;
        while(ss >> word) //takes each word and stores it in a slot on the vector svec1
        {
            svec1.push_back(word);
        }            
    }        
}
```

I’m stuck on getting it to print them 8 at a time, the solutions I’ve tried keep getting subscript out of range errors.

Comment: and be sure to add your print solution so we can help you with the subscript error.

Comment: where are you printing them 8 at a time?

Comment: such short snippets should be inlined here so that your question remains valid even in cast pastebin is shut down (note: did it for you already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < svec1.size(); i++)
{
    cout << svec1[i];
    if ((i+1) % 8 == 0)
        cout << endl;
    else
        cout << " ";
}
```

?

EDIT:
the solution above outputs extra space/newline at the end. It can be avoided by something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < svec1.size(); i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
        /*do nothing or output something at the beginning*/;
    else if (i % 8 == 0)
        cout << endl; /*separator between lines*/
    else
        cout << " "; /*separator between words in line*/
    cout << svec1[i];
}
```

Comment: Unsure how to directly reply so facebook style it is
nathan: I scrapped that after the 50th time of it not working, it was a horrible mess anyway.

leon: Learning C++ from a book, doing this was one of the exercises>

phresnel: thank you, I'll keep this in mind in the future.

@Vlad I'll try this now, thanks a bunch

Comment: @user863492: you can use "add comment" link below the comments to the question.

Comment: @Vlad: Change that `int index` to `int i`.

Answer (score 0):

Walk over your vector with an index:

```
for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < svec1.size(); ++idx) {
   std::cout << svec[idx] << sep(idx); // sep(idx) is conceptual; described below
}
```

What is this `sep(idx)`? It is the separator to print after the idx<sup>th</sup> word. This is

- A newline after having printed eight words on a line. idx will be 7, 15, 23, etc: One shy of an integer multiple of 8. In code, `(idx+1)%8 == 0`.
- A newline for the last item in the vector; you probably want the last item to be followed with a newline. In code `idx+1 == svec.size()`.
- A space otherwise.

An easy way to do this is with the ternary operator:

```
for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < svec1.size(); ++idx) {
   const char * sep = (((idx+1)%8 == 0) || (idx+1 == svec.size())) ? "\n" : " ";
   std::cout << svec[idx] << sep;
}
```

If you don't like that,

```
for (unsigned int idx = 0; idx < svec1.size(); ++idx) {
   const char * sep;
   if (((idx+1)%8 == 0) || (idx+1 == svec.size())) {
      sep = "\n";
   }
   else {
      sep = " ";
   }
   std::cout << svec[idx] << sep;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally you iterate over a vector using a `for` loop clause. So if you want to print all elements of your `vector<string>` you have to make something like this:

```
for(vector<string>::iterator it = myvec.begin(); it != myvec.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *it;
}
```

*EDIT:* as Vlad has posted correctly, you can also use array indices, which are less efficient in lists, but equally efficient with vectors.